# Rails 4 strong parameters Unknown parameter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Simple one-to-many relationship going on and getting a Unpermitted parameter in the server log.

Cup 1----*> Contacts

The params looks like

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ay/wRwJTr4u5Vgu5oOrk7z4RC/OfeLJdN9WXuoyU7iQ=", "cup"=>{"name"=>"cupname", "location"=>"Somewhe", "type_ids"=>"1", "contact"=>{"first_name"=>"Greg", "last_name"=>"Ander", "email"=>"email@me.com", "telephone"=>"444906398"}}, "commit"=>"Create new cup"}
```

In *cups_controller.rb*

```
class CupsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @cup = Cup.new(cup_params)
    render nothing: true
end

private
        def cup_params
            params.require(:cup).permit(:name,:location,:type_ids,   
                :contacts_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone ])
        end
```

In *cup/new.html.erb* - f is the main form for cup

```
<%= f.fields_for :contacts do |contact_info| %>    
      <%= contact_info.label :first_name %><%= contact_info.text_field :first_name %>
      <%= contact_info.label :last_name %><%= contact_info.text_field :last_name %>
      <%= contact_info.label :email %><%= contact_info.email_field :email %>
      <%= contact_info.label :telephone %><%= contact_info.telephone_field :telephone %>
      <% end %>
```

Keep getting `Unpermitted parameter contact`.

The Cup model has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts`

Model files

```
class Cup < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contacts
    has_and_belongs_to_many :types
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cup
end
```

## Edit

Added updated cup_params and controller class. Also models.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the `contacts_attributes`, not contact itself.

```
def cup_params
  params.require(:cup).permit(:name,:location,:type_ids,   
    contacts_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone ])
end
```

Comment: tried that too, strangely I keep getting the same in the server log.